# What's the syntax for setting a Swift Delegate to a view controller other than "self"?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, delegates, protocols

I have a simple program with a navigation controller and seques created to switch between 3-5 screens.  The data is in the main view controller, and I have correctly set up a delegate and protocol between the main and 2nd view controllers.  The problem I am having is that I am not sure how to set up a proper delegate between the main view and the third view.  My main hangup is over the overriding of the prepareForSegue function.

Because the program flows one screen at a time (The main segues to the 2nd view, and the 2nd view segues to the 3rd view, etc.) I am not sure where and how I should use this function.  I have set up the main view to adhere to the 3rd view controller protocol, but I'm just not sure how to set it as the delegate.

For example, I know that if I override the prepareForSegue function in the 2nd view controller, I can't use "self" as the delegate.  I want to make the main view be the delegate, but I'm not sure what the syntax is to make a non-"self" view a delegate.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "2ndViewTo3rdView"{
        let thirdVC:ThirdViewController = segue.destinationViewController as ThirdViewController
        thirdVC.delegate = (????)
    }
}
```

I attempted something along the lines of "navigationController?.topViewController, but I get the following error: Type 'UIViewController' does not conform to protocol 'ThirdViewDelegate'

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this solution for modally presented VC's where:

- customVCOneA may present customVCThree
  -Or-
- customVCOneB may present customVCTwo
  -Then-
- customVCTwo presents customVCThree
- customVCThree sends instructions to clear form data on customVCOneB only.

## For Swift 5:

### In customVCThree (Sending the instructions or information)

Outside the Class:

```
// Establish protocol for communicaiton back to parent view controller.
protocol ClearVCOneBProtocol {

    // State the method that communicates back to grandparent view controller.
    func clearVCOneB(/*Other Desired Parameters*/)

}
```

Inside the Class (Not in any function):

```
// Declare the delegate used to communicate with parent view controller.
var delegate: ClearVCOneBProtocol?
```

Inside the Class (Trigger protocol method as required for your app):

```
    // As View Controller is about to disappear.
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

        // Check "Restoration Identifier" (set inside Interface Builder or by code).
        if presentingViewController?.restorationIdentifier == "customVCTwo" {

            // Instruct the delegate to clear the form.
            delegate?.clearVCOneB()

        }
        else {

            // Do NOT instruct the delegate to clear the form.

        }

    }
```

### In customVCOneB (Receiving the instructions or information)

Outside the Class:

```
// Extend the View Controller with the protocol and delegate methods.
extension customVCOneB: ClearVCOneBProtocol {

    // Conform to ClearVCOneBProtocol protocol.
    func ClearVCOneBProtocol(/*Other Desired Parameters*/) {

        // Call a function that has been declared inside customVCOneB and/or access parameters included in protocol.
        resetForm()

    } // End ClearVCOneBProtocol.

} // End extension.
```

### In customVCTwo (Intermediary beween customVCOneB and customVCThree)

Wherever customVCThree is instantiated and presented:

```
    // Create the View Controller.
    let newVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: customVCThree) as! customVCThreeViewController

    // If customVCTwo was presented by customVCOne...
    if presentingViewController?.restorationIdentifier == "customVCOneB" {

        // Set customVCOneB as the delegate of customVCThree.
        customVCThree.delegate = presentingViewController as! customVCOneBViewController

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

`navigationController?.topViewController as? YourClassThatConformsToThirdViewDelegate`

You would need to replace `YourClassThatConformsToThirdViewDelegate` with the relevant class in your case.

The key is the `as? YourClassThatConformsToThirdViewDelegate` part. `UIViewController` obviously does not conform to `ThirdViewDelegate`, so I feel casting would do the trick.

Comment: I tried that, but it it is still giving me a "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" when I attempt to use my delegate function in ThirdViewController such as "delegate!.protocolFunction(String Variable)"  I assume this is because the delegate is not being assigned to it and is coming up as nil?  Similar code is in the 2nd view and runs correctly with the "self" tag used, so it seems to revolve around setting that delegate correctly I believe.

Comment: I would inspect the contents of navigationController.viewControllers and figure out what's going on. Perhaps, topViewController is not giving you the desired viewController. But, it's just a guess!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and for the sake of someone else needing an alternative answer, here ya go.  I solved this by passing the receiving VC as a parameter in prepare(forSegue:) to a variable.

```
if let secondVC = (segue.destination as? UINavigationController)?.topViewController as? CustomViewController {
            secondVC.firstVC = self
        }
```

Then in my secondVC, create an instance of the thirdVC that i want to have the delegate like this:

```
let thirdVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "thirdVC") as? ThirdViewController
        thirdVC?.Delegate = firstVC.self as! Delegate
```

Hope this helps someone